# How can I parse this IRC message in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, irc

So in my python IRC bot I get raw messages from IRC that look like this

> :testuser!testuser@testuser.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #channel :Kappa

I only want my bot to display the username, channel and the message. How can I filter the data so that I only see this?

Answer (score 0):

To get the message, do this:

```
msg = "Your-message"
msg.split(":", 2)[2]
```

Through, I don't know how to get the user.

Answer (score 0):

To get the user:

```
 msg[1:].split('!')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply do like this.

```
def privmsg_channel(self, data: str) -> str:
    try:
        sender, command, channel, *args = data.split(" ")
        _nick = str(sender).split('!')[0].split(':')[1]
        data = ' '.join(args)[1:]
        _data = (f'<{_nick}>{data}')
         
    except:
        pass
         
    return data
```